# ActionBarActivity Show/Hide toolbar not working properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

I am currently developing an app wherein I need the feature to hide the toolbar on scrolling down (like Google+). I am facing issues with it's rendering of toolbar on scroll. Here is how it looks now -

[image: Overlapping view on toolbar]

I want the toolbar to simply hide on scroll down, but here the view is partially covering the toolbar and after that only toolbar is hiding.

This is the layout code -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.step.main.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

And here is the `Activity` code -

```
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHide() {
                hideViews();
            }

            @Override
            public void onShow() {
                showViews();
            }
    });

    private void hideViews() {
        mToolbar.animate().translationY(-mToolbar.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2));
    }

    private void showViews() {
        mToolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
    }
```

Can someone explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it after reading this line on `FrameLayout` doc -

```
"Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top."
```

So, I interchanged the position of `Toolbar` and `RecyclerView` and it worked. Here, `Toolbar` is rendered after `RecyclerView`, so it is higher in the stack.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.step.main.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</FrameLayout>
```